# cloudflare worker rewrite Host Header

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

How do I set up another Host Header in the cloudflare worker?
For example, I have set up a 1.2.3.4 ip for my site's www record
By default www requests are sent with the header www.ex.com but I want to send the www requests with the new.ex.com header

Comment: Just create a CNAME record for the name new.ex.com that points to www.ex.com, and you don't need to change the host header, just send your requests directly to new.ex.com. If the DNS record points somewhere else, then you need to use resolveOverride in @KentonVarda answer. But either way you need to have a DNS record for new.ex.com for it to work. If you don't want new.ex.com to resolve to a usable IP you can create an AAAA record with value 100::

Answer (score 4):

You need to configure a DNS record for `new.ex.com` so that it points to the same IP address. Then, you can make a `fetch()` request with `new.ex.com` in the URL.

If you cannot make `new.ex.com` point at the right IP, another alternative is to make a `fetch()` request using the `resolveOverride` option to specify a different hostname's IP address to use:

```js
fetch("https://new.ex.com", {cf: {resolveOverride: "www.ex.com"}});
```

Note that this only works if both hostnames involved are under your zone. [Documentation about `resolveOverride` can be found here.](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/reference/apis/request/#the-cf-object)

You cannot directly set the `Host` header because doing so could allow bypassing of security settings when making requests to third-party servers that also use Cloudflare.

Comment: Hi Kenton, will it be possible to use this worker to allow me to access my webserver via IP address? For example, if the user types `https://123.123.123.123` in chrome it will fetch it from www.my-domain-url.com?

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Parse the URL.
let url = new URL(request.url)

// Change the hostname.
url.hostname = "check-server.example.com"

// Construct a new request
request = new Request(url, request)
```

Note that this will affect the Host header seen by the origin
(it'll be check-server.example.com). Sometimes people want the Host header to remain the same.

```js
// Tell Cloudflare to connect to `check-server.example.com`
// instead of the hostname specified in the URL.

request = new Request(request,
    {cf: {resolveOverride: "check-server.example.com"}})
```